# Wordpress REST RESPONSE API Float value is Big

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am working wordpress rest endpoint, returning float value when it's showing response it is taking maximum decimal values. before sending it i rounded but it's not working.

```
    ini_set( 'precision', '6' );
    echo floatval($data['float_value']);
```

if i echo the value that is giving 45.45.but in my rest response,

```
 "float_value": 45.4500000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
 "created_at": "2020-06-18T11:58:06",
 "updated_at": "2020-06-19T10:50:46"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ini_set is overriden somewhere in middle of script.

you can do like this

```
$new_num=number_format((float)$num, 2);
```